# Search array with specific key value pair

Tags: php, arrays, list

Assume I have this array list in php

```
[
  {
    "id": "1",
    "name": "test1",
  },
  {
    "id": "2",
    "name": "test2",
  },
]
```

How can I easily return the id that have name=test1?

Comment: Try array_search

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using `array_search()`. First, get the place of the *id, name* pair and get the content of the *id* field next.

```
//Get the key of the 'id, name' pair
$key = array_search('test2', array_column($input, 'name'));

//Get the id beloning to the name
$id = $input[$key]->id;
```

A working example [here](https://ideone.com/AcmmUG).

Comment: This is the cleanest and fastest way. It works perfectly. Many thanks

Answer (score 0):

I assume you have multilevel array, so you do using foreach function as below.

```
$x= array(array('id'=>'1','name'=>'test1'),array('id'=>'2','name'=>'test2'));
foreach($x as $value){
if($value['id'] =="1" && $value['name'] == "test1"){
// Do your stuff
}
}
```